# Logstash log ftp input

Tags: logstash

Hithere,

My log files is stored in remote server where the directory is only accessible via browser.

Each day if there is a new log files uploaded in the server, it will be stored like this,

```
fttp://serverip.com/logs/2014/10/08/log.txt  
ftttpp://serverip.com/logs/2014/10/08/log2.txt
fffttpp://serverip.com/logs/2014/10/08/log.xml  
fffttttppp://serverip.com/logs/2014/10/08/log.xlx
```

the timestamp would be the time its uploaded to the server(i can use curl to see its timestamp)

```
input {
    exec {codec => plain { }
    command => "curl ftp://serverip.com/logs/2014/10/08/" #this list the dir
    interval => 3000}
            }
    output {
            stdout { codec => rubydebug }
            #elasticsearch {embedded => true}
        }
```

the problem is how can i combine/link the timestamp with the event file in the directories, because there is no timestamp in the log files.